# Cannot load riched20.dll into memory

Tags: windows-xp, ms-sql

In WindowsXP 64bit while installing MSSQL 2008 installation terminates showing error message "Cannot load riched20.dll into memory..." How to fix it?

Comment: [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290234) says to find `riched20.dll` (probably in `c:\windows\system32`) and rename it, then run either `instmsi.exe` or `instmsiw.exe` from the installation CD. [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291651) says rename the file and then run the program’s repair (if you haven’t installed it yet, then rename the file before installing). And [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938194) has a 64-bit version of the file available, but it’s for Vista (though it should still work in XP).